# Grails/java: Exception in Multi-tenant data source provider javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc:mysql: is not bound in this Context

Tags: java, grails, plugins, grails-plugin, multi-tenant

**First of all please review my steps which I followed are correct or not.**

When I create new user by URl `http://com.cust:8080/sampleapp/user/create` it's working but issue is that is not using database which I configure for domain `com.cust` i.e `custdb` instead using `sampleappdb` which is global in DataSource.groovy.

And in **user** table its adding **tenant id** with **0** as Value instead **2**

And on console I'm getting error `Exception in Multi-tenant data source provider
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc:mysql: is not bound in this Context`

I am configuring a basic sample application with multi-tenant plugin.

I have followed below steps to configure multi-tenant plugin.

1. Created `sampleapp` grails project
2. Executed grails `create-domain-class com.myapp.User`
3. Executed `generate-all com.myapp.User`
4. configured `MySQL` database to use
5. installed plugins

   ```
   plugins.multi-tenant-core=1.0.3
   plugins.multi-tenant-ehcache=1.0.1
   plugins.falcone-util=1.0
   ```
6. Executed command `grails create-data-source-map`
7. Executed command `grails create-dns-map`
8. Executed command `generate-all tenant.DataSourceTenantMap`
9. Executed command `generate-all tenant.DomainTenantMap`
10. Annotated User domain class with `@MultiTenant`

    ```
    package com.myapp
    import grails.plugin.multitenant.core.groovy.compiler.MultiTenant

    @MultiTenant
    class User {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        static constraints = {
        }
    }
    ```
11. Added tenant block in config.groovy

    ```
    tenant {
            mode = "singleTenant"
            datasourceResolver.type = "db"
            resolver.request.dns.type = "config"
            resolver.type = "request"
            domainTenantMap {
                localhost = 1
                com.cust = 2
            }
    }
    ```
12. Executed below sql command

    ```
     INSERT INTO data_source_tenant_map ( VERSION, data_source, mapped_tenant_id) VALUES (0 , "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cust1db?user=user&password=pwd" , 1)
     INSERT INTO data_source_tenant_map ( VERSION, data_source, mapped_tenant_id) VALUES (0 , "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/custdb?user=user&password=pwd" , 2); 
     INSERT INTO domain_tenant_map ( VERSION, domain_name, mapped_tenant_id, NAME) VALUES (0 , 'localhost', 1,'Sample Localhost'); 
     INSERT INTO domain_tenant_map ( VERSION, domain_name, mapped_tenant_id, NAME) VALUES (0 , 'com.cust', 2,'127.0.0.1');
    ```

**DataSource.groovy**

```
 development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/sampleappdb?autoreconnect=true"
        }
    }
```

Using **grails 1.3.7** version.
Please help stuck from last 1 week. **Thank You.**